# What's the role of the chainmail and scale armor on InSight's WTS?

Tags: mars, insight, thermal

It's like taken directly from a medieval armor...

[image]
[image]

The role of wind and thermal shield (WTS) deployed over the seismometer is in its name - protecting it from noise and thermal changes. This is fairly clear - and achievable by classic means; a rigid protective shell on the outside, possibly a padding on the inside, the "bellow" skirt to align it with the uneven ground... but I just don't see where the chain mail and scale mail skirts come into the picture. Other than being rather heavy (pulling the kapton skirt to the ground) - which could be achieved by other (admittedly less cool looking) means, I don't see their role. Especially that neither was famed for being particularly good against heat, cold or wind.

How do they help in thermal and wind protection?

Comment: What, no `chainmail` tag? I'll advocate for that if you advocate for a [Gilligan's Island tag](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25636/identify-this-rocket-and-launch-site-from-gilligans-island-episode#comment74491_25636).

Comment: Perhaps to protect against pointy bits on the Martian surface?

Comment: Allied with @ChrisB.Behrens comment. It might be a simple way to provide a flexible seal with the ground to minimize gaps between the ground & the protective skirt.

Comment: Chainmail alone would suffice for that. Or even a spongy bottom seal.

Comment: Mars *is* named after the roman god of war, after all. Better come prepared.

Comment: @sf needs to be wind proof and stay flexible at low temperatures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The extendable skirt is bordered around its circumference by a kind of chain-mail, not unlike that worn as armour by medieval knights. Its weight alone allows the skirt to descend. Its platelet structure also confers a second advantage, namely its ability to effectively cover obstacles such as pebbles, enveloping their surfaces and hence sealing off the WTS." -- https://www.seis-insight.eu/en/public-2/seis-instrument/wts