# How many independent demonstrations of optical communications between ground and space have been successful?

Tags: history, communication, record, optical-communication

As everybody knows, the pioneering work of The Professor and his serendipitous collaborator Gilligan demonstrated the reality of ground to space optical communications [back in 1964](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0588095/). In that case information was encoded in the incandescent radtaion of soot particles via *spatial modulation*<sup>1</sup> rather than the more modern *temporal modulation*.

The launch of this crewed and remarkable mission can be seen [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25636/12102).

**Questinon:** Since that "fateful trip", how many independent demonstrations of optical communications between ground and space have been successful?

---

<sup>1</sup> https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0588095/mediaviewer/rm2807151617

Answer (score 3):

Probably the first and only ground to space optical communications experiment with an object *on the lunar surface* was a laser communication line with Lunokhod-2.

> "Эта же наземная аппаратура была использована для эксперимента по
> исследованию возможности передачи информации методом время-импульсной
> модуляции по оптическому каналу связи Алма-Ата - "Луноход-2". Объект
> использовался для ретрансляции сигналов на Землю по радиоканалу.
> Пропускная способность данной линии связи равна 15 дв.зн/сек."
>
> The same ground-based equipment was used for an experiment to study
> the possibility of transmitting information by the method of
> time-pulse modulation over the optical communication channel Alma-Ata - Lunokhod-2. The object was used to relay signals to Earth via a radio channel. The throughput of this communication line is 15
> two-digit characters per second.
> http://russianspacesystems.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/1973_Radiotekhnicheskiy_kompleks_Luna21_Lunokhod_2.pdf

Comment: "дв.зн." probably means "двоичных знаков", "binary digits" (i.e., bits).

Comment: I'm still hoping for a complete answer but this is so important (and since it's expiring) I'll award the bounty here. *Thanks!*

Comment: But Lunokhod-2 was only used for laser ranging. All it had onboard were retro-reflectors, which reflected light sent from Earth. You're talking about a ground-based experiment but I cannot find any translatable reference to laser communication with respect to this mission.

Comment: @Polar_Bear page 62 "Прибор ФА010"

Answer (score 3):

Quite a few. Indeed the first ever use of lasercom space-to-ground was in 1994. This was achieved by Japan’s 1-Mb/s laser link to ground from the ETS-VI satellite in GEO.

Here are some state-sponsored missions, achieved as well as planned. Source: [Development Current Status and Trend Analysis of Satellite Laser Communication](http://www.photon.ac.cn/article/2021/1004-4213/1004-4213-2021-50-4-0406001/T1.html)

| State/ organization | Terminal name | Launch time | Major institutions | Communication distance | Communication wavelength | Communication rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | GOLD | 1995 | NASA JPL | GEO→GND | 830 nm（downlink） | 1.024 Mbps@PPM（downlink） |
| USA | GOLD | 1995 | NASA JPL | GEO→GND | 514.5 nm（uplink） | 1.024 Mbps（uplink） |
| USA | GeoLITE | 2001 | MIT LL | GEO→GND | / | / |
| USA | LRO | 2013 | NASA GSFC | Lunar→GND | 1064.3 nm（downlink） | 300 bps@PPM（downlink） |
| USA | LLCD | 2013 | NASA GSFC | Lunar→GND | 1550 nm（downlink）1558 nm（uplink） | 622 Mbps@PPM（downlink） |
| USA | LLCD | 2013 | NASA GSFC | Lunar→GND | 1550 nm（downlink）1558 nm（uplink） | 20 Mbps@PPM（uplink） |
| USA | OPALS | 2014 | NASA JPL | ISS→GND | 1550 nm（downlink） | 30~50 Mbps@IM/DD（downlink） |
| USA | OCSD-B | 2018 | NASA | LEO→GND | 1064 nm（downlink） | 50 Mbps/100Mbps@IM/DD（downlink） |
| USA | LCRD | 2021 | NASA GSFC | GEO→GND | 1550 nm（duplex） | 2.88 Gbps@DPSK（duplex） |
| USA | LCRD | 2021 | NASA GSFC | GEO→GND | 1550 nm（duplex） | 622 Mbps@PPM（duplex） |
| USA | ILLUMA-T | 2022 | NASA GSFC | LEO→GEO | 1550 nm（duplex） | 1.244 Gbps@DPSK（return link) |
| USA | ILLUMA-T | 2022 | NASA GSFC | LEO→GEO | 1550 nm（duplex） | 51 Mbps（forward link） |
| USA | TBIRD | 2022 | NASA MIT | LEO→GND | 1550 nm（downlink） | 200 Gbps（downlink） |
| USA | TBIRD | 2022 | NASA MIT | LEO→GND | 1550 nm（downlink） | 5 kbps@PPM（uplink） |
| USA | O2O | 2023 | NASA JPL | Lunar→GND | 1550 nm（downlink） | 80 Mbps@PPM（downlink） |
| USA | O2O | 2023 | NASA JPL | Lunar→GND | 1550 nm（downlink） | 20 Mbps（uplink） |
| USA | DSOC | 2022 | NASA JPL | Mars→GND | 1550 nm（downlink）1060 nm（uplink） | 264 Mbps@PPM（downlink） |
| USA | DSOC | 2022 | NASA JPL | Mars→GND | 1550 nm（downlink）1060 nm（uplink） | 2 kbps（uplink） |
| USA | LOCNESS | 2025 | NASA GSFC | GEO→GEO | / | 100 Gbps（GEO→GEO/GND） |
| USA | LOCNESS | 2025 | NASA GSFC | GEO→GND | / | 10 Gbps（GEO→LEO） |
| USA | LOCNESS | 2025 | NASA GSFC | GEO→LEO | / |  |
| Europe | SILEX | 2001 | ESA | LEO→GEO | 847 nm（LEO） | 50 Mbps@IM/DD（LEO） |
| Europe | SILEX | 2001 | ESA | GEO→GND | 819 nm（GEO） | 2 Mbps@PPM（GEO） |
| Europe | TerraSAR→X | 2008 | DLR | LEO→LEO | 1064 nm（duplex） | 5.6 Gbps@BPSK（duplex） |
| Europe | EDRS-A | 2016 | ESA | GEO→GEO | 1064 nm（duplex） | 1.8 Gbps@BPSK（duplex） |
| Europe | EDRS-A | 2016 | ESA | GEO→LEO | 1064 nm（duplex） | 1.8 Gbps@BPSK（duplex） |
| Europe | EDRS-C | 2019 | ESA | GEO→GEO | 1064 nm（duplex） | 1.8 Gbps@BPSK（duplex） |
| Europe | OPTEL-μ | 2018 | RUAG | LEO→GND | 1550 nm | 2.5 Gbps@IM/DD（downlink） |
| Europe | OSIRISv3/4 | 2020 | DLR | LEO→GND | 1500 nm | 10 Gbps@IM/DD（downlink） |
| Europe | EDRS-D | 2025 | ESA | GEO→GEO | 1064 nm/1550 nm（duplex） | 3.6 Gbps~10Gbps@BPSK（duplex） |
| Europe | HydRON | 2025 | ESA | GEO→LEO | 1064 nm/1550 nm | 100 Gbps |
| Europe | HydRON | 2025 | ESA | GEO→GND | 1064 nm/1550 nm | 100 Gbps |
| Japan | ETS-VI | 1994 | NICT | GEO→GND | 830 nm（downlink） | 1.024 Mbps@PPM（downlink） |
| Japan | ETS-VI | 1994 | NICT | GEO→GND | 514.5 nm（uplink） | 1.024Mbps（uplink） |
| Japan | OICETS | 2006 | JAXA/NICT | LEO→GND | 847 nm（downlink） | 49.3724 Mbps@NRZ（downlink） |
| Japan | OICETS | 2006 | JAXA/NICT | LEO→GND | 815 nm（uplink） | 2.048 Mbps@PPM（uplink） |
| Japan | SOTA | 2014 | NICT | LEO→ GND | 980/1550 nm（downlink） | 1 Mbps~10 Mbps@OOK（downlink） |
| Japan | VSOTA | 2019 | NICT | LEO→GND | 980/1550 nm（downlink） | 1 kbps~1 Mbps@OOK/PPM（downlink） |
| Japan | JDRS | 2020 | JAXA/ NICT | GEO→LEO | 1540 nm（return link） | 1.8 Gbps@RZ→DPSK (return link) |
| Japan | JDRS | 2020 | JAXA/ NICT | GEO→LEO | 1560 nm（forward link） | 50 Mbps@IM/DD（forward link） |
| Japan | HICALI | 2021 | NICT | GEO→GND | 1500 nm（downlink） | 10 Gbps@DPSK（downlink） |

Answer (score 0):

Laser communication in space is the use of free-space optical communication in outer space. Communication may be fully in space (an inter-satellite laser link) or in a ground-to-satellite or satellite-to-ground application.

The main advantage of using laser communication over radio waves is increased bandwidth, enabling the transfer of more data in less time.

> In November 2014, the first-ever use of gigabit laser-based communication as part of the European Data Relay System (EDRS) was carried out. Further system and operational service demonstrations were carried out in 2014. Data from the EU Sentinel-1A satellite in LEO was transmitted via an optical link to the ESA-Inmarsat Alphasat in GEO and then relayed to a ground station using a conventional Ka-band downlink. The new system can offer speeds up to 7.2 Gbit/s.The Laser terminal on Alphasat is called TDP-1 and is still regularly used for tests. The first EDRS terminal (EDRS-A) for productive use has been launched as a payload on the Eutelsat EB9B spacecraft and became active in December 2016. It routinely downloads high-volume data from the Sentinel 1A/B and Sentinel 2A/B spacecraft to the ground.

***So far (April 2019) more than 20000 links (11 PBit) have been performed.***

This Wikipedia gives more answers: [Laser Communication in Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_communication_in_space)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is true that for spacecraft in low Earth orbit radio is limited in bandwidth compared to optical. But there are *other* advantages to using optical for LEO besides bandwidth. With a wavelength roughly 10,000 times smaller, the "antennas" are now small telescopes of 5 to 50 cim in diameter rather than meter to tens of meters, and fast pointing and tracking is a lot easier because they are both compact and well, they are *telescopes* and so can more easily track signals by imaging the transmitted spot and in some cases other things as well.

Comment: But for deep space applications, let's say to Mars or Jupiter or even the Kuiper belt, bandwidths are far lower than radio is capable, and that's because the wavelengths are centimeters. Antenna gains on the ground are 40 or 50 dB only, and those big dishes on spacecraft are 10 to 20 dB. Where optical communications really "shines* (pardon the pun) is for deep space. A 30 cm telescope will have a gain of 120 dB, but one at each end and you will have a much stronger signal. This is not because the bandwidth *per se* is bigger, but because the signal is larger than thermal noise over wider freq.

Comment: Also, the question asks "How many independent demonstrations...?" not how many "links". To answer you'll need to count the number of independent demonstrations that were successful. I think that the answer is a half-dozen or less, not "20,000".

Comment: Here's an example of a link budget calculation where those gains can be used to calculate a data rate: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/50575/12102