# How far apart do both SpaceX half fairings splash down?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, fairings

Inspired by [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27565/how-does-spacex-decide-which-half-of-the-falcon-9-fairing-to-catch): How far apart from each other (both in space and time) do the two halves of a Falcon fairing land? I'd also be curious to know what's the error margin they have on this.

SpaceX tweet mentions that the fairing landed about 50m from the ship, but that doesn't tell us if that's their precission marging or just pure luck (we can safely guess that they won't just sail around the pacific carrying a huge net in the hope that they magically fall into it, but who knows).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is a specific answer.  They are using parafoils that can aim for a target, so every mission will have different numbers, based on the test case they are trying for. Thus they do not have a standard, single answer to that question.

There has been much speculation that one half could fly faster, and try to land on Mr. Steven (or his ilk) then the other half could try to fly a slower route to linger, and provide enough time  to lower the caught fairing half, and reset for the second one.  This is postulated as one approach SpaceX might take instead of using two distinct ships. Time will tell as SpaceX is not really talking about specifics yet.