# Temperature indicators/labels on space debris?

Tags: spacex, debris, temperature

There was a picture in this [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31438/) about space debris on shore. Seems to be a part of a Falcon 9.

[image]

The round stickers are used for temperature control. Similar labels are sold by some companies, for instance [Spirig](http://www.spirig.com/index.php?id=127?&L=0). The labels do permanently record exceeded temperature levels by permanently blackening the corresponding former white indicating levels. But the time and duration of eceeding the level is not recorded.

[image]

But what temperatures should be recorded, during launch preparation, atmospheric flight or reentry? Apparently the temperature was higher than the record interval of 40, 43, 46, .. 104 and 110 °C as all dots are black.

Comment: Possibly used prelaunch to show that required payload environments are not exceedef.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: If used to show that required payload environments are not exceeded, these labels should be applicated at the fairing or the payload adaptor and not at the rocket. The labels should be inspected just before launch when human access is still possible.

Comment: How do you know they are not on the fairing or the payload adaptor?

Comment: I do not  know they are not on the fairing or the payload adaptor. In this [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31438/) the part with the labels is described as a Falcon 9 part.