# In Starman's roadster, where's the Towel?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy, tesla-roadster

Did Starman forget his towel? A towel is the essential thing every explorer needs to carry, right? Can't get very far without it.

Comment: I'd be more interested to know if Starman knows where it is ;)

Comment: If you are going to have something yelling "Don't panic" then you do need a towel :)

Comment: Re: Mat's Mug; I joined this community just so I could push the question closer to 42 votes.  XD  (Although its also an excellent question!)

Comment: @ThunderGuppy I was tempted to downvote it back down to 42, on principle, but I'm being a good boy!

Comment: I did downvoted it to get it back to 42. Jake, please write some more answers (or even a self-answer)  so I can upvote them to balance it out. Excellent question, and it deserves to be at 42 to be perfect!

Comment: Let me in on the joke, guys. what's with the towel?

Comment: @NVZ Read  the Hitchiker's Guide to the Galaxy, at least the first dozen pages. Long story short, it's pretty important to always have one with you.

Answer (score 58):

According to Elon Musk's Twitter it's [in the glove compartment](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/939005893634506752), alongside a copy of Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy, and the Foundation series on the Arch disk.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me!  That is totally icing on the cake!

Comment: This is the answer bro

Comment: Joined this community just to say I'm not going to upvote this answer because it's at +42 and that is just... perfect.

Comment: I had to downvote to bring it back to 42.

Comment: Let's downvote this answer and upvote other @CBredlow questions/answers instead. We need to get this answer back to 42. CBredlow has some good questions like [this one](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24990/did-the-fairings-from-the-falcon-heavy-test-flight-get-recovered)

Comment: FWIW I came back to upvote. If people are *downvoting* answers, then the game isn't fun anymore.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - you are SO wrong. Downvoting **this specific answer** back to 42 makes it just perfect. Upvote other answers to balance the karma. Have you read "Hitchhiker guide to Galaxy"? If not, you should. [42 is the universal answer to life and everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42))

Comment: @PeterMasiar I appreciate the sentiment and hate to be the party pooper but technically that would be targeted voting and is explicitly not allowed by SE rules.