# How often has the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy been in space?

Tags: spacex, iss, record, astronaut-lifestyle, tesla-roadster

I came across an [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25034/37183) saying that a copy of [the Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) was sent to space in Elon Musks roadster (in 2018).

Has the book been in space before that (maybe taken to the ISS by an astronaut)?

If yes, how many copies were up there in total?

Comment: I'm still waiting for a [Babel Fish](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Babel_Fish). Maybe [Majikthise](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Majikthise) or [Slartibartfast](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Slartibartfast) could help ;-)

Comment: Signs point to yes: https://spaceflight101.com/iss/wp-content/uploads/sites/37/2015/09/exp42-768x1024.jpg

Comment: More general question that would be interesting is how many actual _printed books_ (novels etc., not technical checklists and the like) have been to space in total. It seems very unlikely that this would have been done at all since the 90s, with E-book-viewing-capable devices being much lighter than paper (and/or needed anyway for other purposes – laptops), but on earlier Shuttle missions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been there 3 times

1. Michael Foale took it to Mir in 1997.
2. Samantha Cristoforetti [brought it to the ISS](https://www.openculture.com/2015/05/italian-astronaut-reads-the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy-on-the-international-space-station.html) (International
   Space Station) in 2015. She actually brought it up to read, not
   symbolically.
3. As you said in the question, it was brought with Starman on Falcon Heavy's demonstration mission.

Comment: Nice. Incidentally, do you know about the crew poster with her in it, where they dressed up like the movie? https://planetary.s3.amazonaws.com/web/assets/pictures/20141121_exp-42-hitchhiker-poster.jpg

Comment: As in it wasn't brought to space because the astronaut had read and loved the book, it was brought for her to actually read it. @OrganicMarble

Comment: Woops, I see I left that same comment about the poster on the question. Oh well.