# How to determine $\Delta v$ loss due to gravitational pull from earth

Tags: launch, orbital-mechanics, rockets, trajectory

How do I find the delta-v loss of a rocket while ascending to its apogee?

Specification of Atlas V 541 rocket:

- Specification for Atlas V first stage:

  - Dry Mass: 21054 kg
  - Fuel and Oxidizer(RP1/LOX) Mass:284,089kg
  - (Isp)(SL) = 311 seconds
  - (Isp)(vac) = 338 seconds
  - Thrust(SL) = 3,827 KN
  - Thrust(vac) = 4,152 KN
  - First stage wet mass: 305,143 kg
  - Liftoff TWR: 1.179
  - Maximum TWR: 9.06 (Will be throttled down due to G-Force)
  - Operating time: 253 seconds
- Specification for Atlas V second stage:

  - Dry Mass: 2,243 kg
  - Fuel and Oxidizer (Hydrolox) = 20,830 kg
  - Fairing: 1,500 kg
  - Equipment and imaginary payload: 600 kg
  - (Isp)(vac):449.7 seconds
  - Thrust(vac) = 101.8 KN
  - Second stage wet mass: 25,673 kg
  - Minimum TWR : 0.404
  - Maximum TWR : 3.105
  - Operating time: 926 seconds
- Rocket Total Mass (Both Stages): 330,816 kg

Comment: Can you please edit that wall of text for readability?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Ok, I would edit the wall of text for convenience. In fact, I have no idea how to edit the wall of text. But I will try.

Comment: Click the word "edit" below the text.  Put in some line breaks at least.  You can also use the list formatting tools found in the menu line above the text box.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have updated, do you mind check it again?

Comment: Much more readable. I see what you did there :)

Comment: You'll get better answers if you try to show what work you have done so far. Just "How do I do X?" may not inspire many answers. One problem would be that it is hard to tell exactly what it is you know already and don't know, and it's no fun taking time to write an answer to then find out "oh I know that already, what I really want to know is Y!" Can you outline how you think you might calculate it? Or at least link to the definition of $\delta v$ loss that you are using? It makes it easier to give an answer that you'll find helpful.

Comment: Does trajectory matter? Is it defined exactly the same if you are launching to LEO, GEO or "just straight up"? Do you want to use the imaginary 600 kg payload, or something bigger?

Comment: Not that it helped much, but I improved the accessibility of the question by replacing the inaccessible image with the equivalent text.

Comment: @uhoh -- Trajectory matters.

Comment: @DavidHammen re the formatting, probably not the best use of your time today, but there's a certain fun to putting the world ever so slightly more in order. I'd gotten half-way through doing it myself, and then thought *Hey, isn't this something the OP should learn how to do?*

Comment: @Raze it's a good time to learn some basics of text editing in stackexchange. Looks like you will be an active member here or in other sites, which is great! To save screen space, I think a single carriage return is always ignored. But two in a row will give you a blank line. At the top of the edit window you can insert bullets. Something also useful is adding four spaces at the beginning of each line. This is used mostly for code, but it is also handy for tables or lists, and it changes to monospaced font but no more extra blank lines. [See here](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/20012/12102).

Comment: @uhoh: Trajectory matters because 1) it defines ISp as function of air pressure, 2) it decides upon thrust split between horizontal accelerations and climb + gravity losses. We can find it two ways; a) from Tsiolkovski's equation, in function of ISp(altitude(t)) and final orbital velocity, working on delta-v directly, spent vs achieved; or as b) thrust * cos( angle of burn(t) ) * altitude; work and energy spent to climb vs potential energy (as altitude in gravitational field) gained. In both cases trajectory is necessary.

Comment: @SF. It was *a rhetorical question for the OP*. I'm asking the OP to decide if it matters to their question, and in fact suggesting that they think about it and consider mentioning something about it as part of my [recommendation to improve the question](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20848/#comment56507_20848). I still have zillions of unanswered questions *asked as questions* - help yourself  - please! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the problem known as launch trajectory optimization. That is a complicated problem mostly requiring a numerical simulation. That does however not mean we can obtain some useful figures and insights from an analytical approach!

To begin, we can with an inaccurate but usable estimate. The flawed assumption is as follows: "Our rocket is fighting against gravity for a time of $T$, so the lost $\Delta v=Tg$"

The Atlas rocket is flying for $253s+926s=1179s$, so the lost $\Delta v=1179s \cdot g=11500\frac{m}{s}$. That is more than the total $\Delta v$ of the rocket...

So what is the problem? Turns out force is a vector quantity and not a scalar. Our rocket is mostly not accelerating in the direct opposite direction of gravity, in fact, we want to gain velocity normal to gravity to reach an orbit.

If we draw some force vectors we can clearly see that the total acceleration is larger than the value we get from simple subtraction, depending on the angle. (Accelerating downwards, we even get a small bonus from gravity).

[image: force vectors]

Complication 1: **$\Delta v$ loss depends on trajectory**

But there are more things to consider than this. For instance, why does the rocket not have to fight gravity anymore? Well, it has gained orbital velocity. But "orbital velocity" is not a binary toggle, everything is an orbit, the slower ones just happen to intersect Earth, not desirable for a satellite.

Instead, we are thrusting against a "vertical acceleration" (The direction of course varies while we are orbiting, so we are viewing this in a rotating frame of reference). We can express this from the circular orbital velocity, $v_c$:

$$a_{vertical} = 1 - \frac{v_{horizontal}^2}{v_c^2}$$

Complication 2: **The vertical acceleration depends on velocity**

So, an ideal strategy would be to gain horizontal velocity as fast as possible, with just enough vertical acceleration to counteract gravity. This is not very useful though as the drag is going to be extremely large and your rocket will end up crashing into the side of a mountain.

A compromise is to start in an almost vertical position, and always accelerate parallel to the current velocity vector. This is efficient as adding together vectors in parallel gives the longest resulting vector. Thir trajectory also has the nice property that the gravitational acceleration is going to slowly turn the rocket horizontal. With some planning, the rocket ends up with orbital velocity at the target altitude. This is known as a [gravity turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_turn).

You now have:

- Horizontal acceleration, depending on gravity and vertical velocity
- Gravity, depending on altitude, depending on vertical acceleration over time
- ...
- And a ton more.

The resulting system of differential equations is way to complicated to solve properly.

On top of that, you have to consider the atmosphere, as that affects your trajectory (and $I_{SP}$...)

**TL;DR** You must use a numerical simulation.

So then, **how** could such a simulation be implemented? Here is a quick sketch: (svg source in answer source for anybody wanting to improve it)

[image: ascent trajectory]

1. Initial ascent (red). Accelerate vertically, and simulate drag losses. Most of those should be here.
2. Gravity turn (blue). Start to pick up some horizontal velocity, and let gravity turn your rocket over. Repeat this for multiple angles to get your preferred final altitude. Ignore drag for this part.
3. Final orbit (pink). No more acceleration required.

Comment: Gravity turns don't simply burn along the direction of movement. There's an initial purely vertical ascent, a small adjustment to get a small horizontal velocity component, an ongoing adjustments to keep the trajectory optimized. All of this is very nearly aligned with the direction of movement, but it's a tightly controlled process.

Comment: @Schlusstein You are completely right, you can generalize the manoeuvre in that way. It is equivalent of saying that the initial velocity can be something else than zero.

Comment: I thought the **tl;dr** goes at the beginning, or are you being clever rendering it moot by putting it at the end, where one sees it only after reading? Or does it in fact stand for *too late; did read*? :)

Comment: @uhoh Let us assume that for a GTA (general text area), somebody has some RC (reading coefficient) between 0 and 1, where 0 is simply looking at the length and 1 is completely reading the text. Let us further assume that there exists a threshold of RC so that for any value below it somebody does not see the bold-text "TL;DR". Your claim is then that the introduction sentence ∉ GTA so *everybody* can see the "TL;DR" part regardless of their specific RC at the moment, the *purpose* of such a text is to have a threshold close to 1. Is that an accurate analysis of your comment? **TL;DR** :P

Comment: I'll do some Monte Carlo simulations, and get back to you. ;) Right now I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: @Hohmannfan, if you have tools for that kind of numerical simulation, there's an ongoing community wiki which is building a list of these: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/790/software-tools-for-space-exploration-available-online .

Comment: @Schlusstein A gravity turn, by definition, keeps the rocket pointed directly along the direction of movement (except in the pitchover after the initial ascent). An optimal launch trajectory is not a gravity turn -- at least, not unless the rocket has been carefully designed so it cannot survive the aerodynamic forces of any trajectory but a gravity turn. Which is not wholly unrealistic, since rockets are designed to be as light as possible.