# Payload fairing separation- Event based or time based?

Tags: rockets, trajectory, launch-vehicle, fairings, separation

Refer the answer for this question [How strong and "hot" is the wind on the payload after the fairing is deployed at ~110km?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20012/how-strong-and-hot-is-the-wind-on-the-payload-after-the-fairing-is-deployed-at)

It is clear that the fairings are separated when the free molecular aero-thermal flux is less than 1135 W/m2, which usually happens at an altitude of around 110 km.

If the separation is event based, how are they measuring the flux? Else, the separation is timed for the altitudes?

Comment: It's not necessarily either-or. Possibilities for knowing the altitude can also include rocket-based GPS receivers and on-board inertial guidance system.

Comment: @uhoh, So the separations are happening with respect to altitude?

Comment: You listed two possibilities, A or B, I listed two more and these happen to be related to altitude. I would guess that they check the solar activity, make a prediction on the temperature of the upper atmosphere, and calculate the altitude necessary to get to 1135 on launch day, then use that altitude. But it could be a fixed altitude as well. There might be some jitter depending on other parameters as well; let's see what answers people post.

Comment: I would be surprised if it's not a simple timer.