# Why the payload fairing separation occurred at high altitude of 183 km for Vega C VV21?

Tags: fairings

For various launch vehicles it usually it occurs at altitude around 110-120 km range but for inaugural launch of Vega C flight VV21 payload fairing jettison altitude seems too high, why is it so?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!

The excellent answer to this question [How strong and "hot" is the wind on the payload after the fairing is deployed at ~110km?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20012/how-strong-and-hot-is-the-wind-on-the-payload-after-the-fairing-is-deployed-at) tells us that most boosters jettison the fairing when the heat flux drops to < 1135 W/m<sup>2</sup>.

However, the [Vega C User's Guide](https://www.arianespace.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/SSMS-Vega-C-UsersManual-Issue-1-Rev0-Sept2020.pdf) states

> 2.3 Aerothermal flux at fairing jettisoning
>
> Jettisoning of the payload fairing can take place at different times depending on the
> passengers aerothermal flux requirements.
> Typically, for SSO missions, the fairing separation takes place 5s after Z9 ignition around 270
> seconds from lift-off and the **aerothermal flux is lower than 300 W/m<sup>2</sup>** .

(emphasis mine)

So this booster is waiting for a lower value of the heat flux to jettison the fairing, compared to the other boosters.

*Why* that is, I do not know.

Comment: The lower heat flux after fairing separation may allow payloads with less heat protection. So some weight may be used for electronics, propellants or solar panels instead of heat protection.